# Map.erase() throws an error, why?

Tags: c++, caching, dictionary, sfml

I've been making a simple sprite cache for SFML2 sprites. I have a manager class which holds a map of pointers to sprites. And i also have a sprite class which holds a reference to it's owner map. Now the issue is in the destructor of the sprite. It looks like this:

```
~ActualSprite()
{
    if(m_iteratorLocation != m_ownerMap.end())
    {
        m_ownerMap.erase(m_iteratorLocation);
    }
}
```

m_iteratorLocation is supposed to be the current location of the sprite in the sprite map.
It gets initialized in the sprite constructor and here is the sprite creation method from the sprite manager

```
SpritePtr getSprite(SpriteId name)
    {
        if(!spriteMap[name])
        {
            spriteMap[name] = std::tr1::make_shared< ActualSprite >(spriteMap, spriteMap.find(name));
            clipSprite(name);
            return spriteMap[name];
        }
        else
            return spriteMap[name];

    }
```

Basically when i exit the program i get an exception/error message stating: `Expression: map/set iterator outside range`.

At first i thought that this happens because `spriteMap.find(name)` can't find the name and returns `spriteMap.end()` instead. But i don't get it, doesn't the first mention of `spriteMap[name]` add the `name` key to the map? Anyway i then added the if statement to only erase the map entry if the iterator doesn't equal .end() but it still pops up.

Basically now instead of an iterator i use the name enum for erase and it works but i still wish to know why i was getting the error message.

This is the full code with the current working version, and the commented iterator version which throws the error.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <map>


enum SpriteId
{
    ITEM1,
    ITEM2,
    ITEM3,
    ITEM4,
    ITEM5
};

const int WIDTH = 100;
const int HEIGHT = 100;

class ActualSprite;

typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr< ActualSprite > SpritePtr;
typedef std::map< SpriteId, SpritePtr > SpriteMap;

class ActualSprite : public sf::Sprite
{
private: 
    //SpriteMap::iterator m_iteratorLocation;
    SpriteMap &m_ownerMap;
    SpriteId &m_name;
public:
    //ActualSprite(SpriteMap &ownerMap, SpriteMap::iterator iteratorLocation) : m_ownerMap(ownerMap), m_iteratorLocation(iteratorLocation)
    //{}

    ActualSprite(SpriteMap &ownerMap, SpriteId &name) : m_ownerMap(ownerMap), m_name(name)
    {}

    ~ActualSprite()
    {
        m_ownerMap.erase(m_name);
    }

    //~ActualSprite()
    //{
    //  if(m_iteratorLocation != m_ownerMap.end())
    //  {
    //      m_ownerMap.erase(m_iteratorLocation);
    //  }
    //}
};

class SpriteManager
{
private:
    SpriteMap spriteMap;
    sf::Texture& m_texture;
    void clipSprite(SpriteId name)
    {
        spriteMap.at(name)->setTexture(m_texture);
        switch(name)
        {
        case ITEM1: spriteMap.at(name)->setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT));break;
        case ITEM2: spriteMap.at(name)->setTextureRect(sf::IntRect((1*WIDTH),0,WIDTH,HEIGHT));break;
        case ITEM3: spriteMap.at(name)->setTextureRect(sf::IntRect((2*WIDTH),0,WIDTH,HEIGHT));break;
        case ITEM4: spriteMap.at(name)->setTextureRect(sf::IntRect((3*WIDTH),0,WIDTH,HEIGHT));break;
        case ITEM5: spriteMap.at(name)->setTextureRect(sf::IntRect((4*WIDTH),0,WIDTH,HEIGHT));break;
        //default: exception or somethin'
        }
    }
public:
    SpriteManager(sf::Texture& texture) : m_texture(texture)
    {}
    SpritePtr getSprite(SpriteId name)
    {
        if(!spriteMap[name])
        {
            spriteMap[name] = std::tr1::make_shared< ActualSprite >(spriteMap, name);
            /*spriteMap[name] = std::tr1::make_shared< ActualSprite >(spriteMap, spriteMap.find(name));*/
            clipSprite(name);
            return spriteMap[name];
        }
        else
            return spriteMap[name];

    }
};

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800,600), "Test", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);

    sf::RectangleShape background(sf::Vector2f(800.0f,600.0f));

    window.setFramerateLimit(30);

    sf::Texture spriteSheet;

    if(!spriteSheet.loadFromFile("SpriteSheet.png"))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    SpriteManager sprites(spriteSheet);

    SpritePtr sprite = sprites.getSprite(ITEM2);
    SpritePtr sprite2 = sprites.getSprite(ITEM4);

    sprite->setPosition(100,100);
    sprite2->setPosition(200,100);

    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while( window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left))
            {
                sf::Vector2i currentPos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
                sprite->setPosition((static_cast<float>(currentPos.x) - (WIDTH/2)), (static_cast<float>(currentPos.y) - (HEIGHT/2)));
            }
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(background);
        window.draw(*sprite);
        window.draw(*sprite2);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** This is just a test so that's why everything is in a single .cpp file and why the item names are not descriptive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely with the fact that the destructor of your map, embedded in the `SpriteManager` object, iterates through all of its elements in order to remove them. Upon removal/destruction of the stored shared pointers, if these are the last shared pointers to your objects, the destructor of your `Sprite` gets invoked.

In turn, this will try to use the stored iterator to remove the corresponding element from the map. However, the element pointed to by this iterator has just been removed from the cycle in the map's destructor and, therefore, invalidated. Passing the iterator as an argument to `erase()` eventually results in Undefined Behavior (which in your case luckily manifests itself as a crash).

The problem of course will show up even if the removal of the shared pointers from the map does not directly cause the destructor of your `Sprite` to be invoked (because there are other shared pointers which point to it): in that case, in fact, the elements in the map must have *already* been erased, and you're left with an invalidated iterator. When the destructor of `Sprite` will be called, it will pass an invalid iterator to `erase()`, resulting again in Undefined Behavior.

Comment: I think this is the correct reason, as `std::map` iterators aren't invalidated on erase.

Comment: @AndreiTita: Not iterators to elements other than the erased one(s). However, iterators to the erased elements are invalidated.

Comment: @AndyProwl I see, thanks for the answer. `Passing the iterator as an argument to erase() eventually results in Undefined Behavior (which in your case luckily manifests itself as a crash).` Does this sentence refer to my case only or should i refrain from using iterators as arguments to `erase()` in general? Also does my `.erase(name)` actually do anything now? Judging from what you said, having `.erase()` in my code isn't necessary at all?

Comment: @MrPlow: Using iterators as arguments to `erase()` is fine, if you take care of not using invalidated iterators. The call to `erase(name)` searches the item to be removed by key, which is safer in this case, because the value of the key is never "invalidated", but as you guessed, has no effect, because the corresponding element has been removed from the map already (and no duplicates are allowed, since you used an `std::map` and not an `std::multimap`). So finally, yes, the call to `erase()` in your destructor is not necessary.

Comment: @AndyProwl Oh, I see. However if i remove the call to erase in my sprite destructor, wouldn't that leave keys with empty pointers in the map during the execution? I mean if I'm making a game and remove the sprite when it's not needed, wouldn't the map entry still be there, except now with an empty pointer? Taking up memory? That was basically my initial point of inheriting a sprite class and adding this destructor. Or have i messed up in my thought somewhere?

Comment: @MrPlow: If your map is holding `shared_ptr`s to your sprites, those sprites won't ever be deleted unless you first remove the `shared_ptr`s from the map. `shared_ptr`s are used for shared ownership, so as long as at least one of them exists, your object won't be destroyed. Putting the call in the object's destructor is useless, because the object gets destroyed when there are no more `shared_ptr`s to it. This means that the corresponding entry is not in the map anymore. You probably want your map to have only observing, non-owning pointers to the sprites. If so, you may check out `weak_ptr`.

Comment: @AndyProwl Oh, that makes sense... I don't yet know how to use `weak_ptr` nor how to implement it into this code i have now, but that looks like what i want. Damn, as soon as i think i finally did something right it ends up being useless. But that's programming i guess. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

A map of shared_ptr's will call the destructor of the object when it's erasing it.

The destructor of the contained object in your case erases the object.

You are GOING to run into all sorts of weird issues doing this.  Using weak_ptr won't solve the problem either.  Might hide it at best.

Also, this code doesn't do what you think it does:

```
if(!spriteMap[name])
    {
```

The `std::map` container creates the object with that key if it doesn't exist.  What you want to use, if you want to test for existence, is `find`.

It just so happens you've luckily fallen on some nice consequences of the object you're containing.   A shared_ptr will be zero initialized, and a null shared_ptr tests false when using the bool operator.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `SpriteMap`, containing a `shared_ptr<Sprite>` is (shared) owner of the `Sprite` objects which it contains. Thus a `Sprite` may only be destroyed, after it was removed from the containing `SpriteMap`. At that point the iterator that used to point to this `Sprite` in the map has become invalid.

In your code this happens when the `SpriteManager` is destroyed at the end of `main()` as explained by @Andy Prowl. The same would happen, if you had operations to dispose of `Sprite`s at any other time.

If you want `Sprite` lifetime to be managed by the `SpriteManager`, you don't need the self-unregistering code in the `Sprite` destructor. If you want `Sprite` lifetime to depend only on usage outside the `SpriteMap`, you could make the `SpriteMap` hold `weak_ptr<Sprite>`. In that case you could keep that self-unregistering code - or leave expired pointers in the map until the next access attempt.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? My arguments meanwhile all have been integrated into the accepted answer, but at least some them were first explicitly stated in my answer. (Seems I'm still struggling to grasp the bylaws of this community)

Comment: I just upvoted, this is valid information against good use case scope.